# JSON Parser error

Tags: java, android, json

I keep getting a JSON parser error every time I try to connect from android to php account. Below you will see the error I am getting:

```
08-16 10:45:23.002: E/JSON Parser(848): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Can someone help me please...

PHP code:

```
else{
            //Store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            }else{
                //User failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Oops something went wrong! Please try late.";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

Android COde:
Android code:

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params){

```
    //making HTTP request
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //Try parse the string to a json object
    try{
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    //return JSON string
    return jObj;
```

Register user JSONObject

```
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        //building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        //Getting JSON object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);

        //return json
        return json;

    }
```

PhP warning:

```
08-16 10:45:22.990: E/JSON(848): <br />n<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\thryfting_api\include\DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />n{"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Oops something went wrong! Please try late."}n
```

php code:

link 89 is the $no_of_rows

```
public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ' $email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Users table structure:

```
create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

mysql_error:

```
08-16 14:09:20.550: E/JSON(1028): <br />n<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\thryfting_api\include\DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />nNo database selected{"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"No database selected"}n
```

Comment: Without code it is hard to say what you did wrong, but from message it is clear that you are trying to convert non-JSON string to JSONObject.

Comment: Please post your code and the string you are trying to dejsonize.
However, from your exception it looks like you are trying to convert an invalid json string to `jsonOBJECT`.

Comment: please Log the `json` and share that as well.

Comment: What is the URL. Could you type it here? My guess is, you got a PHP fatal error. If you were to go to that URL, I bet you would see the PHP error.

Comment: @tolgap It's being tested on a localhost but I get a warning instead of an error I just posted it

Comment: Could you also post your `users` table structure

Comment: @tolgap I posted the structure

Comment: well, JSONObject() constructor expects a valid json string.So you are getting exception beacause of this warning : `<br />n<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\thryfting_api\include\DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />n`
Please remove this warning first from your response somehow and give he constructor a warning-less valid json.

Comment: This is valid json from your response:
`{"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Oops something went wrong! Please try late."}` 
Give this string to the `JSONObject()` constructor.

Comment: We are gonna need more info on how you persist your Database Connection, seeing as the error tells you that there is no DB connection. Could you put your DB_Connect.php and DB_Functions.php on PasteBin?

Comment: Yes, i just pasted it, how do i share it with you? (I'm new to paste bin)

Comment: You are strongly recommended to stop using the `mysql_xx()` functions. They are considered obsolete and are no longer maintained. The PHP manual has notices recommending switching to either the newer `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

As [tolgap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366455/tolgap) pointed in his comment, the fact that you have something about "br" looks like your page is sending back a PHP error, with its HTML formatting (hence the BR) instead of the JSON string. You should try and fix that error first.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Missing __ before construct in php